# Mysql using like with two variables in different tabel

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `a` and `b`.

`Table a` has a field named `gr` which can have multiple values concatained with string.

`Table b` holds it seperately in fields `lg`.

How do i run the below query to check whether `b.lg` is in `a.gr`?

```
 SELECT lg FROM `a`,`b` WHERE a.`id` =22 AND  (a.gr LIKE '%'+b.lg+'%')
```

Comment: post the schemas for your 2 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use CONCAT function try:

```
SELECT lg 
FROM a, b 
WHERE a.id = 22 AND  
      a.gr LIKE CONCAT('%', b.lg, '%');
```